bounded density for the determinant of a GOE
Let $M$ a random GOE matrix, i.e. $M=(M_{i,j})$ is a symmetric matrix and the $M_{i,j},i\leq j$ are independent centred Gaussien entries with variance 1, except on the diagonal where the variance is $2$.
Does the determinant has a bounded density in 0? i.e. is there $C$ finite such that $$P(|\det(M)|<a)<Ca$$
for $a>0$?
It seems rather classical but it is not immediate in the random matrix litterature.

sorry i started a bounty by mistake
